# Large array pasted into Xcode playground and project stops it running

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I pasted an array with about 700 elements into

Each element looked like this [138, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (so it's an array of arrays)

When the playground attempted to run it cam up with this error message in a pop up box

'Communication with the playground service was interrupted unexpectedly

The playground service "com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground" may have generated a crash log.'

If I delete enough elements it works again.

Is there any way of getting it to work?

I have the same issue when pasting the array into a project.

When I try and run the app the build fails and I get a Command failed due to signal: Segmentation 11

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Give the array a type.  `var myArray:[[Int]] = [[138, 0, 0...`.

Comment: @LeoDabus, what happened to your duplicate?  Did you unmark it?

Comment: @vacawama i don't know. It became a single vote

Answer (score 0):

In the immortal words of Groucho Marx:

"Doc, it hurts when I do *this*."

"Then don't do that!"

Playgrounds are pretty fragile and the playground engine is buggy. I'm not at all surprised that there are things that you do in a playground that crash it. I suggest a couple of things:

```
1. Post a bug to Apple's bug reporter. Repeatable crash 
2. Use a different method of loading your large array.
```

For #2, try an explicit type for the array as suggested in the other post.

Failing that, I would suggest using a plist, and the method `arrayWithContentsOfFile`. You could create a small array in code and save it to disk, then edit the plist file in a text editor to contain your large data set and copy it into your project. Finally, add code to load it using `arrayWithContentsOfFile`.